# Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be the biggest prime number of $5$ different digits. Find the result of $n\mod 37$.

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be the biggest prime number of $5$ different digits. Find the result of $n\mod 37$.

I tried decreasing numbers from $98765$ to $98731$  and I verified them as being prime online, and $98731$ is the the most bigger prime number and $98731 \mod 37 = 15$, so the answer must be $15$.

Also I was trying to use the property of a prime number such that:

> Any prime number can be write as $6k + 1$ or $6k + 5$, for any $n > 3$.

but, not only prime numbers can be write as $6k + 1$ or $6k + 5$, so I reached quickly a deadend.

Still, this question should be solved without calculator and I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Just a nitpick: any prime other than $2,3$ can be written as $6k+1,6k+5$.

Comment: What is the context of this question?

Comment: I don't see how to avoid a search of some sort.  I mean, $98713$ is prime, and all the digits are distinct, and thats $34\pmod {37}$. I don't see how to be sure that this one isn't maximal without a search.

Comment: Hint: $1000\bmod{37}=1$.

Comment: @MIke It's just a question in an exam.

Comment: @NoOne You were not given a calculator? Then this is just a problem of searching primes effectively. Once you find the prime, it's easy to find it mod $37$ via my hint.

Comment: @DonThousand Yeah, no calculator allowed :))

Comment: @DonThousand I don't see how your hint can help me.

Comment: @NoOne has this exam ended?

Comment: Well, $98731\bmod{37}=700+(9+3)\cdot10+8+1\bmod{37}=15$.

Comment: @DonThousand  But why would you have picked $98731$ in the first place?  just confirming that this is prime would be a tedious pencil and paper process.  And you'd still have to eliminate all the greater possibilities.

Comment: @JitendraSingh yeah, I didn't even participate. It's just some exercise.

Comment: @lulu As I said in my previous comment, "Once you find the prime, it's easy to find mod $37$"

Comment: @DonThousand  Well, true.  The hard part is definitely finding the prime.

Comment: Actually, I found $98731$ from the following set $(98763, 98761, 98753, 98751, 98743, 98741, 98733, 98731, ... )$, which is sorted in non-increasing order, and I just test each number until I found $98731$. I could eliminate other numbers because the last digit of a number cannot be even, it should be smaller then the last digit of the number and the digit should not repeat.

Comment: But you need to test each of these for primality.  That's easy enough with a calculator but without? I mean, the square root is around $314$ so this is pretty tough with pencil and paper.

Comment: Well, it does seem reasonable enough that there is a prime of the desired form where the first 3 digits are 987. And then when you consider the next digit has to be 6 or lower, then the last digit can only be 1 or 3, that leaves not so many to check. But I'm not sure how easy it is to check whether a number around 100,000 is prime in the first place. But then again, once you find that prime, it seems like dividing it by 37 and keeping the renainder is a cinch.

Comment: Actually, it's reasonable easy if you use the property for the form of primes number, the one that I wrote in the question.

Comment: Yes but the converse is not always true: it is easy to see that 98733 is not prime but it takes more work to show that 98731 is prime.